# Memory issue with TabView and TabViewStyle (SwifUI)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, tabview

There is a "BUG" on iOS and with SwiftUI.

I have created a small project that you can download to reproduce it.

Here the issue: On swipe with the configuration tabViewStyle the memory is always increasing and never released. Without it, no problem.

```
TabView {
            ImageComponent(name: "jupiter")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Jupiter", systemImage: "circle.fill")
                }
            ImageComponent(name: "saturn")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Saturn", systemImage: "circle.fill")
                }
            ImageComponent(name: "neptun")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Neptun", systemImage: "circle.fill")
                }
            ImageComponent(name: "uranus")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Uranus", systemImage: "circle.fill")
                }
            ImageComponent(name: "pluto")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Pluto", systemImage: "circle.fill")
                }
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle()) // MEMORY ISSUE HERE ON SWIPING. IF REMOVED, IT'S OK.
    }
```

The link for the project if you need it.
[Github Project](https://github.com/rjouvet/PageTabViewBug)

Comment: I just opened an issue on Apple for this problem.

Comment: Has this issue been resolved?  This seems similar to the issue I have.  Just asked a new Stack Overflow question:  "SwiftUI TabView with tabViewStyle page runs in iOS simulator but crashes on device" .

Comment: I don't know yet. I'll try. Apple asked me if it's was still an issue with the new iOS versions, but I changed the way I build the tab. I'll check that today.

Comment: It has be fixed.